# Regex: How to not match word A if word B is somewhere before A

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python regex engine and trying to achieve something like for string `foo,fou,bar,baz`. I want to match `baz` if and only if `fou` is not before it. I've tried negative look behind `(<?!fou)baz` but it doesn't work as it only work for immediate following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re` module does not support variable length lookbehinds, you need to use `regex` module for that.

To get what you want with `re` module, you can use negative lookahead to match `fou` and use a captured group to get `baz`:

```
In [15]: str_ = 'foo,fou,bar,baz'

In [16]: re.search(r'^(?!.*fou.*baz).*(baz)', str_)

In [17]: str_ = 'foo,foz,bar,baz'

In [18]: re.search(r'^(?!.*fou.*baz).*(baz)', str_)
Out[18]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match='foo,foz,bar,baz'>

In [19]: re.search(r'^(?!.*fou.*baz).*(baz)', str_).group(1)
Out[19]: 'baz'
```

In `^(?!.*fou.*baz).*(baz)`:

- The zero width negative lookahead, `(?!.*fou.*baz)`, makes sure `fou` does not come before `baz` in the whole input
- `.*(baz)` puts `baz` in the only captured group

Answer (score 0):

You can even use string methods if you want to avoid the `regex` overhead.

```
string = """
foo,fou,bar,baz
foo,baz
baz, fou
neither nor"""

needle = "baz"
matches = [line
    for line in string.split("\n")
    for fou in [line.find('fou')]
    for baz in [line.find(needle)]
    if line and ((fou == -1 and baz > 0) or (baz < fou))]

print(matches)
# ['foo,baz', 'baz, fou']
```

To save a variable `x` in a list comprehension, you need to use `for x in [...]`.